# google-analytics How to view multiple websites in one single account

Tags: view, google-analytics

I´m new on this of Analytics, and I need help on something pretty basic... I have a Demo Account where I noticed the view has 3 different IDs (websites), but all of their stats are shown in one single view.. I have 5 Websites right now on my GA, but I can´t go through making all 5 websites stats to be in one single view.. Any help on this? How can I organise them?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily about reporting, and not about coding.

Comment: Try asking this on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Usually you place each website in a separate property. Each property has its own tracking code that you would place on the corresponding site. Instructions for setting up a property can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1042508?hl=en).